# Secure way to upload files to GCP Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We're making some machines in which there's a part which uploads the images captured by the camera to Google Cloud Storage. For this purpose what I've done is

1. Create a service account for each machine.
2. Create a custom role with
   permissions:

> ```
> storage.objects.create
> storage.buckets.get
> storage.objects.get
> ```

3. Apply this role to that service account.
4. Download the JSON credentials key file and use this file with python script (in which I specify bucket name) to upload image to GCP Storage.

Is this way of doing things efficient and secure given that we only ship 2-3 machines each month?

Also I will have to ship JSON file with each machine, if the above method is valid, is this fine or there's any method to hide this key file?

Comment: Are you shipping the same service account key on each machine or a different service account key? There is a limit of 10 keys per service account. Do NOT ship the same service account key with each machine. Instead, have the machines request an Access Token from your service - as in your service has the service account and issues tokens (token vending machine). Issue tokens only when required to access Cloud Storage. This will limit the blast radius on a breach.

Comment: Can I make different service account for each machine?

Comment: Yes, but that is also a bad idea. Do you own/control those machines? If yes, that might work but if these go to customers, rethink your strategy.

Comment: Thanks, Can you give me links to read about how to implement Access token method

Comment: You derive an OAuth Access Token from a service account. The Access Token is how you grant rights to access a resource. This is a fundamental concept to understand. Study how service accounts work, how resources are authorized, etc. This is very basic stuff in the cloud.

Comment: How many machine do you expect at the end? Do you ship several machines to the same customer?

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm reading about it. I'll get back when finished.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere No we dont ship several machines to same customer. The number of machines will increase with the number of customers, so there's no end. But the shipment will be slow. Maybe 2-3 machines each month.

Comment: What's the size of the captured image ? Do you need to read the image from the bucket? or the machine only write to the bucket?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere The machine only needs to write the image. Image size may vary.

Comment: What the max image size?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere around 100 MB

Answer (score 2):

Your case isn't so simple!

- Firstly, if you want to put a service account in each machine, you will be limited a day (you are limited to 100 service accounts per project). And using the same service account, or the same key is too dangerous
- Secondly, your use case sounds like IoT use case where you have lot of devices on edge to communicate with the cloud. But PubSub messages are limited to 10Mb max and IoT Core solution doesn't fit with your case.
- The 2 latest solutions are based on the same principle:

  - Make an endpoint public (Cloud Run, Cloud Functions, App Engine or whatever you want)
  - Call this endpoint with your machine, and their own token (i.e. a string, encrypted or not)
  - Check the token, if OK you can (here the 2 alternatives)

1. Create an access token ([short lived token](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials)) on a service account with the minimal permission for the machine usage, and send it back to the machine. The machine will use it to call the Google Cloud API, such as Cloud Storage API. The advantage of this solution is that you will be able to use the access token to reach other GCP APIs in the future if your use case, and your machine update require them.
2. Create a [signedUrl](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) and send it back to the machine. Then the machine has to upload file to this URL. The advantage is the strict limitation to Cloud Storage, no other GCP service.

The main issue with the 2 latest solution is that required public endpoint and you are exposed to attacks on it. You can protect it behind a [load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts) and mitigate the attacks with [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs). Think also to limit the scalability of your public endpoint, to prevent any useless expenses in case of attacks.